# Comparar fechas segun el formato Laravel, vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

estoy usando datepicker para seleccionar fechas en un formulario en donde tengo los campos `fecha de inicio` y `fecha de Finalización` al seleccionar una fecha ya sea la de inicio o fin en el vue tools la pone con el sgt formato `fechaInicio:Wed Feb 12 2020 19:59:00 GMT-0500 (hora de Ecuador)`

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <Label>Fecha de Inicio(*)</Label>
      <datepicker id="select" placeholder="Fecha de inicio" v-model="fechaInicio" :language="es"></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <Label>Fecha de Finalización(*)</Label>
        <datepicker id="select" placeholder="Fecha de finalización" v-model="fechaFin" :language="es"></datepicker> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

y antes de guardar ambas fechas evaluó que la fecha de finalizacion no sea antes de la de inico

```
 if ( this.fechaFin < this.fechaInicio){
     this.errorMostrarMsj.push("La fecha de finalización no puede ser antes de la fecha de inicio");
  }
```

Si pasa la condicion en el controlador las guardo de la sgt manera `Feb 14, 2020`

```
$donacion->fechaInicio = Carbon::parse($request->fechaInicio)->toFormattedDateString();
 $donacion->fechaFin = Carbon::parse($request->fechaFin)->toFormattedDateString();
```

Aqui viene la pregunta xd.. Al querer editar algún otro campo del formulario mas no las fechas entra en la condicion `if ( this.fechaFin < this.fechaInicio)` y no me permite actualizar el registro.. como podria convertir las fechas con el formato que me viene `Feb 14, 2020` para poder evaluarlas??

Comment: puedes formatear la fecha utilizando moment.js
https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues gracias a @George2215 por mencionar lo que podia usar, lo resolvi de la sigt forma a quien interese

Como mencionan en su pagina lo instale, e importe en mi template

```
npm install moment --save   # npm

import moment from 'moment';
```

De lo que tenia:

```
if ( this.fechaFin < this.fechaInicio){
 this.errorMostrarMsj.push("La fecha de finalización no puede ser antes de la fecha de inicio");
}
```

Lo modifique de la sgt manera, en donde antes de evaluar las fechas seleccionadas ya sea para registrar o editar las formateo y después la evaluo

```
var f_Inicio = moment(this.fechaInicio); 
f_Inicio.format();  // 2020-02-27T20:18:58-05:00

var f_Fin = moment(this.fechaFin); 
f_Fin.format();  // 2020-02-27T20:18:58-05:00


 if (f_Fin < f_Inicio){
     this.errorMostrarMsj.push("La fecha de finalización no puede ser antes de la fecha de inicio");
}
```